# Flask csv problem converting string to float

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating an application in Flask and first I need to load a csv base (just numbers) from string to float.

This is a sample of my database:

[image: CSV]

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
import csv
import codecs

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/submit", methods=["POST"])
def submit():
    file = flask.request.files["data_file"]
    if not file:
        return "No file submitted"
    data = []
    stream = codecs.iterdecode(file.stream, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    for row in csv.reader(stream, delimiter =',',  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, dialect="excel"):
        data.append(row)
    
    return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I send the file using: `curl -X POST -F data_file=@'file_name' 'http://localhost:5000/submit'`

I have tried several solutions but cannot convert the data to float. I always get an error like the following:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '142.2;480;1054;1.174653;2.132716;-6.24768;56.534927;50.289242;45.331562;14.43966;767.394409;86.037178;73.907722;1935.5625;5686.896484;13.28'
```

I don't know why I get this error if they are just numbers. In my df there are no null values and no empty spaces.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the delimiter has to be a semicolon instead of a comma.

```
for row in csv.reader(stream, delimiter =';',  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, dialect="excel"):
```